# Adding more detailed parameters to lstinputlisting when importing code?

Tags: hyperref, code, python, import

I'm trying to specifically input python code into a document.  Therefore, I used `lstinputlisting` as such:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, firstline=37, lastline=45, caption={this is a long caption},label={lst:testlabel}]{./code/test_code.py}
```

My first question is, is there an equivalent `listpath` like there is for a `graphicspath` for when you will be importing multiple listings from another directory?  I've searched and I can't find it.

Secondly, what if I want to have a short and long caption for the listing?  Something like

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, firstline=37, lastline=45, caption=[short caption]{this is a long caption},label={lst:testlabel}]{./code/test_code.py}
```

doesn't compile.  Same with additional parameters, like if I want to make the listing a target for `hyperref`.  This:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, firstline=37, lastline=45, caption={this is a long caption},label={lst:testlabel},hypertarget{target}]{./code/test_code.py}
```

doesn't appear to work either.  I would look into using `lstlisting` but it doesn't seem like it would work there either, especially since I'd prefer to import the code to keep it cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets inside optional arguments are not protected, thus `\lstinputlisting` would see `language=..., caption=[short caption` as optional argument and `]` is the file name. Curly braces around the value help:

```
\lstinputlisting[
  language=python,
  firstline=37,
  lastline=45,
  caption={[short caption]{this is a long caption},
  ...
]{code/test_code.py}
```

---

There is no equivalent to `\graphicspath` for listings. Workarounds:

- A macro can be used for the path component at the beginning of the file name.
- Environment variable `TEXINPUTS` could include the source file directories.
- An internal `\input@path` could be set, which also applies to input TeX files, packages, classes, e.g.:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \def\input@path{{pathA/}{pathB/}}
  \makeatother
  ```

---

The hyper target can be set outside the listings at the beginning. The listings itself can cross page boundaries, which is not allowed for link targets.